# Chevy Silverado Fuel Pressure Is Erratic With Rough Idle Only When In Gear

Tags: fuel-system, rough-idle, pressure

I have a Chevy Silverado 2500 with the 6.0L engine and it has been idling rough. When I put it in gear the RPMs start fluctuating and the truck wants to stall out. Once the truck is running down the road, the RPMs smooth out and it runs fine. I put a fuel pressure tester on it to find that once the engine starts stalling the fuel pressure gauge bounces back and forth really fast. There are no engine codes. What could cause these symptoms?

Comment: When was the last time any maintenance work was done to the truck? Plugs, wires, various filters? Also, the year of the truck might help others help you.

Comment: I jus put plugs wires new air filter and fuel filter on its a 2000  chevy silverado 2500 6.0

Comment: Also cleaned the throttle body and replaced egr valve

Comment: Nice, that's a really good start. I would go from there by checking for any vacuum hose leaks and looking at your IAC valve. If the IAC is dirty try cleaning it really well with carb/throttle body cleaner. Also, you could try spraying your mass air flow sensor really well with maf sensor cleaner. These are all cheap and easy things to look at first before really throwing any money at the vehicle.

Comment: Does the symptoms change when you start it with a warm engine?

Comment: How are the fuel trims? Both long term and short term, both banks

Comment: can you verify power and ground at the pump? there will be a wiring harness that runs along the frame if you open it up it'll give you access to the pump power wire. the ground should be on the frame as well towards the leaf spring mounts.

Comment: Ive cleaned the iac and maf both looked good and ill have to put it back on the diagnostic to see what the fuel trim is the fuel pressure is running 47 at idle and when i put it in gear at idle it starts fluctuating really fast when it is at rough idle

Comment: how many amps is the pump pulling does voltage drop out at the pump when this happens? how's the pump amperage waveform? if you pull a line does the pump lph work out to spec?